# didSelectRowAtIndexPath when uiwebview fills cell?

Tags: iphone, uiwebview, uitableview

My controller inherits

`UITableViewController`: `<UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource>`

The cells of the table are custom and are 100% filled by a `UIWebView`

I would like to have the user click anywhere in the `UIWebView` and have the `UITableViewDelegate's` function notified:

```
 - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Is there any suggestion to do like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you create the `UIWebView` set `webView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;`

If you need to allow user interaction within the web view and allow the user to click on the row as well, you'll probably need to do some `UIView` subclassing as a wrapper around the `UIWebView` for allowing you to cancel touches into the `UIWebView` as necessary.